# Error box.col: illegal value on fancyRpartPlot() and rpart.plot() in R

Tags: r, rpart

I am practising the tutorial of 'Titanic: Machine Learning from Disaster' from kaggle.
Could someone please help me with this error ? Its same for the function rpart.plot(fit) and fancyRpartPlot(fit) and example(rpart.plot), While plot(fit) is working fine.

```
fancyRpartPlot(fit) Error: box.col: illegal value
fit is : fit <- rpart(Survived ~ Sex, data=train, method="class")
```

I tried the following:
Followed exact steps as in the implementation in github page (https://github.com/trevorstephens/titanic/blob/master/Tutorial3.R).

Uninstalled and installed the entire R and the added packages.

I tried to debug fancyRpartPlot() and in the function, where

```
box.col = pals[col.index],
pals : chr[1:30] "#F7FCF5" "E5F5E0" "#C7E9C0" .......so on
col.index : num[1:3] 4 5 9
```

box.col will have these values based on index: "#A1D99B" "#74C476" "#9ECAE1"
I tried alot to clear this issue, may be a little problem. What is that i am missing?

print(fit):

```
n= 891
node), split, n, loss, yval, (yprob)
  * denotes terminal node
1) root 891 342 0 (0.6161616 0.3838384)
2) Sex=male 577 109 0 (0.8110919 0.1889081) *
3) Sex=female 314  81 1 (0.2579618 0.7420382) *
```

traceback():

```
6: stop(..., call. = FALSE) 
5: stop0(deparse(substitute(object)), ": illegal value")
4: is.specified(box.col)
3: handle.box.palette.args(obj, trace, box.col, box.palette, pal.thresh, 
   pal.node.fun, node.fun.name, class.stats, node.labs)
2: rpart.plot::prp(model, type = 2, extra = extra, box.col = pals[col.index], 
   nn = TRUE, varlen = 0, faclen = 0, shadow.col = "grey", fallen.leaves = TRUE, 
   branch.lty = 3, ...)
1: fancyRpartPlot(fit)
```

sessionInfo():

```
R version 3.0.2 (2013-09-25)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
locale:
[1] LC_CTYPE=en_IN.UTF-8         LC_NUMERIC=C   LC_TIME=en_IN.UTF-8
[4] LC_COLLATE=en_IN.UTF-8     LC_MONETARY=en_IN.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_IN.UTF-8 
[7] LC_PAPER=en_IN.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                  LC_ADDRESS=C
[10] LC_TELEPHONE=C             LC_MEASUREMENT=en_IN.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base
other attached packages:
[1] RColorBrewer_1.1-2 rpart.plot_2.1.1   rattle_4.1.0       rpart_4.1-10
loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] magrittr_1.5  RGtk2_2.20.31 stringi_1.1.5 tools_3.0.2
```

example(rpart.plot):

```
rprt.p> old.par <- par(mfrow=c(2,2))                    # put 4 figures on one page
rprt.p> data(ptitanic)
rprt.p> #---------------------------------------------------------------------------
rprt.p>
rprt.p> binary.model <- rpart(survived ~ ., data=ptitanic, cp=.02)
rprt.p>                                         # cp=.02 for small demo tree
rprt.p>
rprt.p> rpart.plot(binary.model,
rprt.p+            main="titanic survived\n(binary response)")
Error: box.col: illegal value
```

Comment: After getting the error message please run the following commands and report the output you see:   `traceback()`; `sessionInfo()`.   Please also run `example(rpart.plot)` and see if that works.  Please also email me directly (the maintainer of the rpart.plot package) so we can get this resolved (I will summarize the resolution here for other users).

Comment: i wasnt able to clear the bug. But i installed the latest version R 3.3.3 from the CRAN mirrors and there was no more error.